# Scrapy spider does not collect data from all pages

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy

I am using Scrapy BaseSpider to collect data from a website.  The scraper starts on the product display page and moves on the 'next' page link and collects certain data from each page and stores it into a CSV file.  The spider runs correctly, but collects data from only page 1, page 2 and the last page (page 36).  I can't figure out the reason after several hours of tinkering with the code. The following code shows my spider.  Any suggestions?

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.http.request import Request
from longs.items import LongsItem
from scrapy.utils.response import get_base_url
import urlparse

class LongsComSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "longs"
    allowed_domains = ["longswines.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.longswines.com/wines/?page=3&sortby=winery&item_type=wine"]

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        sites = hxs.select("//div[@class='pagebox']/a[6]/@href")
        for site in sites:
            relative_next_page = site.extract()
            next_page = [urlparse.urljoin(response.url, relative_next_page)]
            if not not relative_next_page:
            yield Request(next_page[0], self.parse)

        products = hxs.select("//div[@class='productlistitem']")
        items = []
        for product in products:
            item = LongsItem()
            item["title"] = product.select("div[1]/h2/a/text()").extract()
            item["link"] =  response.url
            item["price"] = product.select("div[2]/h2/text()").extract()
            item["details"] = product.select("div[1]/p/text()").extract()
            items.append(item)
        for item in items:
            yield item
```

Comment: Your code is broken, see the `for site in sites:` line. The line below is not indented. If you clean it up it will be easier to help you.

Comment: I used this code on different website with similar setup and it works. It doesnt work on this specific site because of some anti scraping mechanism (facepalm).  The lesson here is try the code out in all different scenarios.  Anyway hope the code helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have problem in this line

`if not not relative_next_page:`

you have two `not` there